# Computing the hyperbolic cosine as a serie

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So I want to prove that: 
$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2x}}{(2x)!}=\cosh(\lambda)$$

But, proceeding backwards, the only thing I know is that
$$\cosh(\lambda)=\frac{e^{\lambda}+e^{-\lambda}}{2}=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^x}{2(x!)}+\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda)^x}{2(x!)}$$

And got stuck here, any ideas?

Comment: You are almost finished. Note the cancellation when $x$ is odd.

Comment: Generally looks really strange to use $x$ as an index in a sum. It's not *wrong*, per se, but $x$ usually indicates a continuous value, while indexes like $i,j,k,m,n$ tend to imply integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^n}{2(n!)}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-\lambda)^n}{2(n!)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^{2p}}{2}\frac{\lambda^{2p}}{(2p)!}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{2p}}{(2p)!}
$$ since
$$
\frac{1+(-1)^{2p+1}}2=0,\qquad \quad p=0,1,2,\cdots.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
& \left(1\vphantom{\dfrac{\lambda^3} 6}\right. & + & \lambda & + & \dfrac{\lambda^2} 1 & + & \dfrac{\lambda^3} 6 & + & \dfrac{\lambda^4}{24} & + & \dfrac{\lambda^5}{120} & + & \cdots \\[10pt]
+ & 1 & - & \lambda & + & \dfrac{\lambda^2} 1 & - & \dfrac{\lambda^3} 6 & + & \dfrac{\lambda^4}{24} & - & \dfrac{\lambda^5}{120} & + & \left. \cdots \vphantom{\dfrac{\lambda^3} 6} \right) \\[10pt]
\hline
= & 2\left( 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\lambda^3} 6}\right. & & & + & \dfrac{\lambda^2} 2 & & & + & \dfrac{\lambda^4}{24} & & & + & \left. \cdots \vphantom{\dfrac{\lambda^3} 6} \right)
\end{array}
$$
The odd-numbered terms cancel.